# Convert TikZ to GraphML format

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs

I want to convert TikZ graphs into GraphML format.

Since libraries like [networkxx](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/networkx-1.10/reference/readwrite.html) and [igraph](https://igraph.org/python/doc/tutorial/tutorial.html#igraph-and-the-outside-world) have functions to read and write different formats like:

- GraphViz
- GML
- GraphML
- Pajek format
- Pickled graph
- GEXF
- LEDA
- GIS Shapefile
- ......

Is there any tool/software which can convert TikZ into any of the other formats, and therefore into GrapML format.

Comment: TikZ is a general graphic language and not a format to describe graphs, so I don't think that this is possible. In general the things go the other way round, from data format to graphical presentation.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Apart from the comment of @Kpym there is another important difference: in TikZ you normally set explicit coordinates for all the nodes while in most other graph software the position of nodes is determined by a layout algorithm. That means that when converting you lose the positioning information and the converted graph will look very different. (note that there are also layout algorithms implemented in TikZ but this is a bit exotic/advanced, it requires Luatex among other things).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our team has made a Python tool which allows conversion of Tikz latex code into graphml format which can be opened in [yED](https://www.yworks.com/products/yed). Not all Tikz constructs are supported, but the major ones that are used to make graphs are [supported](https://github.com/ysahil97/tikz-to-yed-graphml#tikz-constructs-supported).

https://github.com/ysahil97/tikz-to-yed-graphml
https://pypi.org/project/tikz2graphml/

Comment: it seems that your question as well answer are advertisement for the tool developed by your team :-). i doubt that this is on-topic her.

Comment: Before developing the tool, we tried to find similar tools which do this (to not reinvent the wheel again). When we did not find a y proper tool, we built one on our own :-).
Gave the link in the answer so that anyone looking for such a tool, can know where to get started.